# Convert this 20110811T131446+0200 to C# dateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm retrieving data from teamcity webservice in json. One of the data is a DateTime represented by this string: 20110811T131446+0200

I would like to parse this string to convert it into a C# .net object.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

PS: It looks like xml data, I could use XmlConvert but the format doesn't contains any "-" as this string 2009-10-29T18:52:53.43-05:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking now, but I think you want to parse with something like:

```
DateTime dateTime;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzzz",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dateTime))
{
    // All was okay
}
else
{
    // Handle failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another posiibility:

```
XmlConvert.ToDateTime("20110811T131446+0200","yyyyMMddTHHmmsszzzzz");
```